# Unable to login after the Ubuntu 15.10 upgrade, logged out automatically

Tags: 15.10

yesterday I have upgraded my laptop to Ubuntu 15.10 from ubuntu 15.04.
After the upgrade i am unable to login, just its logged out automatically.

I have tried these three desktop all returns same results.

What is not working?
1. Gnome Classic
2. Gnome
3. Ubuntu Desktop

what I have tried?
1. Tried to re-install the ubuntu-deskop and unity
2. Created another user, didn't work
3. Tried to remove Xauthority file

Laptop Model:
1. Lenovo G50-70 / AMD A6 CPU

Comment: Press Ctrl+Alt+F1, login to that and then run `startx`. What happens?

Comment: This is the error i am getting.. It shows the login screen, and it logged out in few seconds  
upstart: no-pinentry-gnome3 main process (6582) terminated with status 1
upstart: upstart-event-bridge main process (6624) terminated with status 1
upstart: upstart-event-bridge main process ended, respawning
upstart: upstart-event-bridge main process (6646) terminated with status 1
upstart: upstart-event-bridge main process ended, respawning
upstart: Disconnected from notified D-Bus bus
upstart: job url-dispatcher-refresh failed to stop

Comment: try running `sudo apt-get install unity ubuntu-desktop`

Comment: its not working. already tried it. It works with gnome-metacity, but other desktops are not working :(

Comment: hmm okay if you go into gnome-metacity, then run the command `ccsm` (install if it needs) and then go to OpenGL and disable and then Unity and disable, then enable them both.

Comment: No, its not working..!

Answer (score 0):

I guess I am a bit late to help you but this one is for anyone doing the upgrade now. I had the exact same issue.

For me the solution was to uninstall and reinstall the nvidia drivers. Note that I am here referring to the drivers installed from the nvidia website.

- This is not for the nouveau driver
- This is not for the nvidia-current driver

I am assuming you still have the installer (you can also download it again)

First press CTRL+ALT+F1 to open a terminal and log in. Then do the following:

```
sudo ./NVIDIA-Linux-x86_64-352.41.run --uninstall
sudo reboot (not sure whether needed; but I did it)
```

For me I ended up in an utter mess, but no worries, back to the terminal

```
sudo ./NVIDIA-Linux-x86_64-352.41.run
sudo reboot
```

This did it for me, I hope it can also help others.